# Strange 6 digit numbers found in Borderlands 2

Tags: borderlands-2, borderlands-2-tiny-tinas-assault

What significance do these 6 digit numbers have, found in Borderlands 2?

[image]

```
090312
091283
```

Found in Flamerock Refuge behind the Saucy Stallion Inn.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be an easter egg. Dates most likely. They are found all around the game.

Some people think they are dates, but the events linked to the dates don't seem to have anything in common.

Probably just put in for lols by the developers